# How to add text inside the doughnut chart using Chart.js version 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, chart.js

1. I am using in HTML using Canvas, how to use add the text inside Doughnut chart. Here is my javascript code and and HTML code. I have used chart js version 3.2.1 so please give solution for the same version(3).

```js
var overallStatsCanvasCtx = document.getElementById('pademicOverallStats');
var dataPandemicEmp = {
    labels: ['Normal', 'No Mask', 'Warning', 'High Temperature'],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Overall Statistics",
        data: ['4000', '2000', '1500', '2500'],
        backgroundColor: ['#43C187', '#8FC3F0', '#FFCD5E', '#FF4800'],

    }]
};
var overallStatschartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            align: 'center',
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {

                fontColor: '#474B4F',
                usePointStyle: true,

            }
        }
    },
};
var doughnutChart = new Chart(overallStatsCanvasCtx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: dataPandemicEmp,
    options: overallStatschartOptions,


});
```

```html
<canvas id="pademicOverallStats"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 7):

You will have to use a custom plugin for that

```js
var data = {
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Blue",
    "Yellow"
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ]
  }]
};

var promisedDeliveryChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'text',
    beforeDraw: function(chart, a, b) {
      var width = chart.width,
        height = chart.height,
        ctx = chart.ctx;

      ctx.restore();
      var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
      ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

      var text = "75%",
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.save();
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried but it was not working, as I mentioned I am using chart js version 3.2.1.
Could you please let me know how to use it in version 3.2.1

Comment: Updated to version 3 compatible

Comment: You disabled the legend and don't account for its height use, so the text is not vertically aligned.

Comment: Well the text is vertically aligned just not when you use a legend but in my case it is. But well you can always just add the chart.legend.height to the y nothing stops you

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing an inline plugin and using chartjs version 3.9.1. I have adjusted the other answers to fit my needs which take into account a chart title and legend. The text in the center of the circle is also based on the total of the 0th dataset.

```
plugins: [{
    id: 'doughnutInteriorText',
    beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        var width = chart.chartArea.width,
        height = chart.chartArea.height,
        ctx = chart.ctx;

        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

        var text = chart.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0),
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = (height / 2) + chart.legend.height + chart.titleBlock.height;

        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Blue",
    "Yellow"
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ]
  }]
};

var promisedDeliveryChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'text',
    beforeDraw: function(chart, a, b) {
      var width = chart.width,
        height = chart.height,
        ctx = chart.ctx;

      ctx.restore();
      var fontSize = (height / 240).toFixed(2);
      ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

      var text = "75%",
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.save();
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
```